# R: How turn string '2^23' (or similar) into an integer?

Tags: r

I'd like my R function to accept strings of the form

```
'2^23'
'3^10'
etc.
```

and turn them into integers. Calling as.integer() or as.numeric() on these strings generates an error.

Comment: as.numeric('2^23')

Comment: `eval(parse(text=as.expression("2^23")))` gives `[1] 8388608`

Comment: You should not have such character input. As described, you can only use eval(parse()) which is a good indication of bad software design.

Comment: @AndrewGustar Thanks, Andrew.

Comment: @Roland Suppose I'm taking input from a user, just like R does at the command line. If the user types 2^10 should I process it, or should I tell him his input is "bad"?

Comment: If the user is calling the function they can input an expression instead of a character string. If they put in a character string you should sanitize it and not just eval(parse()).